# Method has (unexpectedly) the same erasure as another method

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, instanceof, type-erasure

I read all the other questions about this, but i can't understand why there is type erasure in my case. I have

```
public <T extends Aclass&Binterface> boolean test(final T param) {
    ...
}

public boolean test(final Aclass pOtherPPShape) {
    ...
}
```

Method test(Aclass) has the same erasure test(Aclass) as another method in type ClassName

How should i write two methods that operate on the same class but one with an interface and one not? (i can't modify the AClass since is from an external library, and have a lot of subtypes with which this code should work)

Is the use of instanceof right in this case?

EDIT:
i use this in a collision test. If the shape passed is instance of an interface, i get a collisionmask(with a method of the interface) and then call the "checker", if it's not, i want to instantiate a dummy collisionmask that does some different stuff and pass to the same method of the "checker" (that has as parameters the 2 shapes and 2 collisonmasks)

Comment: What is it you want to achieve here?  Can you stub-out what you'd like to be doing?

Comment: whats about defining the second method `public <T extends Aclass> boolean test(final T param)`

Comment: They'll still have the same erasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've recognized that the issue is about type-erasure,
and that you can't "overload" on the one parameter with type-erasure in the way
(type-erasure - you will be assimulated).
But, you say,

### The generic type signatures are distinct, why did you get a conflict?

The two types `T extends Aclass&Binterface` and `Aclass` are distinct, aren't they?

Well, yes and no.  While in truth they are distinct, *under type-erasure they're not distinct***1.  An excellent resource explains: "[In the process of type erasure the compiler replaces type parameters by their leftmost bound](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101A)".  Which in your case was `Aclass`, which led to the conflict between the two methods.

The explanation suggests a ...

### Solution: formalize the combound**2 generic type declaration to establish a unique leftmost bound

Replace `<T extends Aclass&Binterface>` with `<T extends AandB>`, where `AandB` is created thus:

1. Define `interface Ainterface` with `Aclass` method signatures
2. Have `Aclass implement Ainterface`
3. Define `interface AandB extends Ainterface, Binterface`.

### OR

you can use `instanceof`.

---

**1 "Because the longer wave lengths are refracted by the particles in the atmosphere", per Duncan Jones, another excellent resource.

**2 That'd be `compound`, cause I couldn't resist the fun :-/

Comment: Ok, but why does type erasure happens? Doesn't the compiler know when it compiles the code if the class is an instance of the Binterface or not, does it? A method with a class as a parameter and a class that also implements an interface is treated the same way?

Comment: Every time i have to do with java generic is fell like they are constricting.. Btw thanks, at the end i choose to use instanceof check: much simpler and much more readable code

Comment: @RichardSitze Because the longer wave lengths are refracted by the particles in the atmosphere ;-)

Comment: @DuncanJones Thanks, I've update my response to include your insights!

Comment: @Makers_F And now I have, I think, a final answer as to why

Comment: Nice answer! Unfortunately i do not have such an Ainterface (but the coder of the engine i'm used created a lot of this interfaces, it's just that the Aclass i'm using is actually a class between shape and sprite), but i like the solution you proposed, even if i think this not trivial solution could be solved if generics had a better design!